# jQuery dynamiclly add elements into DOM

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am trying to select some `img` tags generated by `google map api` using jQuery. In order to be selected, I need to add those on the fly generated elements to the DOM using`on` method. My question: Is there a similar method like `on` without events requirement?
My code:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
    var options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09, -95.71),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypedId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        scaleControl: true
    };
    // Creating the map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, options);
    var EPest_R1 = new google.maps.KmlLayer("https://s3.amazonaws.com/esmapping_kmz/R1.kmz");
    EPest_R1.setMap(map);
    var EPest_R2 = new google.maps.KmlLayer("https://s3.amazonaws.com/esmapping_kmz/R1.kmz");
    EPest_R2.setMap(map);

}
initialize();


function testing() {
    console.log(23);
    $("img").css("opacity","0.2");
}
$('#map').on("mouseover", "img", testing);
```

I tried to customrize an event using trigger which did not work.

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39ddb/49/).